# How parcel.writeString(null) supposed to work on API18?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, parcelable

The parcel.writeString(null); does not persist anything or at least it is not readable. Running the code below will cause the exception below. The test has no problem running on a real device or on an emulator. However if I am running the test in a headless environment using API18 I am having this issue.

```
@org.robolectric.annotation.Config(manifest= org.robolectric.annotation.Config.NONE)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class PersistanceTest {

    private static String TAG = PersistanceTest.class.getSimpleName();

    @Test
    public void testBasicParcel() {
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        parcel.writeString(null);
        parcel.writeInt(10);
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);
        String readBackString = parcel.readString(); // <--Exception here
        int readBackInt = parcel.readInt();
        Log.d(TAG, "read back string: " + readBackString);
        Log.d(TAG, "read back int: " + readBackInt);
        parcel.recycle();
    }
}
```

cause this exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowParcel.readString(ShadowParcel.java:90)
    at android.os.Parcel.readString(Parcel.java)
```

I could not find any documentation that states a change in writeString/readString. Is it a robolectric or an Android API18 issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a robolectric issue, specifically in their implementation of Parcel.  I'd bring this to [their attention](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/).